# What is the name of this type of query, and what is an efficient example?

Tags: performance, query-performance, relational-division

The purpose is to find a parent, given it's children. For example, say you have a marketing package (aka a "combo"), and want to match it based on the products in it. Example table/data:

```
create table marketing_package_product (
  package_id int not null references marketing_package(id),
  product_id int not null references product(id),
  primary key (package_id, product_id)
);

insert into marketing_package_product values 
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,1),
(2,5);
```

Given products 1,2,3, I want to get marketing_package 1. But given products 1,2 only I do not want marketing_package 1.

Is there a name for this type of query, and what is the most efficient way to go about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are solving is called **[Relational Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29)** with two variations, the **"Division with Remainder"** and **"Exact division"** (which fits your description).

See also this article: **[Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)**

This question at StackOVerflow: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)** has a few ways to solve it and benchmarks for Postgres but it's not for the exact variation, only for the *"Division with Remainder"*. The queries will be similar but an extra check/condition has to be added for the exact variation.

One way (of the too many) to solve this would be to self-join the table as many times as the "products" and then an extra check so only packages with these exactly products are kept):

```
SELECT m1.package_id 
FROM marketing_package_product AS m1
  JOIN marketing_package_product AS m2
    ON m2.package_id = m1.package_id 
WHERE m1.product_id = 1
  AND m2.product_id = 2
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM marketing_package_product AS x
        WHERE x.package_id = m1.package_id 
          AND x.product_id NOT IN (1,2)
      ) ;
```

Another would be to `GROUP BY` and then two `HAVING` conditions, one for the division and the other for the "exactness":

```
SELECT m.package_id 
FROM marketing_package_product AS m
GROUP BY m.package_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN m.product_id IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) = @n 
   AND COUNT(*) = @n ;
```

where `@n` would be `2` in this case, the number of products in your check.

Test at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14358/6).