# More efficient way to write multiple "AND"?

Tags: syntax

Anyone know a way to write this in a different manner ?

```
SELECT tableA.NO
FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.NO IN (SELECT GRI_NO FROM tableBB WHERE GRO_NO =62)
  AND tableA.NO IN (SELECT GRI_NO FROM tableBB WHERE GRO_NO =50)
  AND tableA.NO IN (SELECT GRI_NO FROM tableBB WHERE GRO_NO =70)
```

I have many more AND to add and it become quite a long query.  *Does an equivalent of `WHERE GRO_NO IN (62, 50, 70)` exist for `AND`?*

### Edit below:

The equivalence of sampleA1 is sampleA2 for the `OR` keyword.

sampleA1: `WHERE GRO_NO IN (62, 50, 70)`

sampleA2: `WHERE GRO_NO =62 OR GRO_NO =50 OR GRO_NO =70)`

**Does an equivalent of sampleB2 exist for the `AND` keyword ?**

sampleB2:`WHERE GRO_NO =62 AND GRO_NO =50 AND GRO_NO =70)`

---

### Edit2: I'v remove performance tag since it was more related to *clarity / syntax / shorter sql* than DB performance.

Comment: Its unclear what semantics you are desiring here. Do you want the column tableA.NO to be in BOTH the first SELECT output AND in the next one too?

Comment: This type of problem is called [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29). You can see a similar question at dba.se: [What is the name of this type of query, and what is an efficient example?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/what-is-the-name-of-this-type-of-query-and-what-is-an-efficient-example) and one at SO with many (more than 10!) ways to solve it: [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Comment: Efficiency will vary across the different ways with the DBMS, the sizes/distributions of the tables, the indexes and several other parameters. Longer query (in characters) does not mean slower.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that's is faster than what you have, but you can try

```
SELECT tableA.NO
FROM tableA
WHERE tableA.NO
IN 
(
   SELECT GRI_NO FROM tableBB WHERE GRO_NO IN (62,50,70) 
   GROUP BY GRI_NO
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GRO_NO) =3
)
```

Comment: He doesn't look for performancewise efficiency, still +1 because you're the only one so far who has a query which actually gets the same result as the original.

Comment: Indeed, this query work :D.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing a `join` checked with group by and having or `exists` checks

**JOIN**

```
SELECT tableA.NO
FROM tableBB 
    JOIN tableA ON tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO
WHERE 
    tableBB.GRO_NO IN (62,50,70)
GROUP BY tableA.NO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tableBB.GRO_NO) = 3 /* specify the count of GRO_NO's required */
```

**EXISTS** check could be used in line with existing AND check (in OP question)

```
SELECT tableA.NO
FROM tableA
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 'NO is in tableBB' FROM tableBB 
            WHERE tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO AND tableBB.GRO_NO = 62)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 'NO is in tableBB' FROM tableBB 
            WHERE tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO AND tableBB.GRO_NO = 50)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 'NO is in tableBB' FROM tableBB 
            WHERE tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO AND tableBB.GRO_NO = 70)
```

Depending on the distribution of your data you should find one or the other will run faster.

If you needed to expand the criteria of a particular GRO_NO ie: for 70, check that IsActive=1, you could do:

**JOIN**

```
SELECT tableA.NO
FROM tableBB 
    JOIN tableA ON tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO
WHERE 
    tableBB.GRO_NO IN (62,50,70)
    /* GRO_NO specific clause */
    AND ((tableBB.GRO_NO = 70 AND tableBB.IsActive = 1) OR tableBB.GRO_NO != 70)
GROUP BY tableA.NO
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tableBB.GRO_NO) = 3 /* specify the count of GRO_NO's required */
```

**EXISTS**

```
SELECT tableA.NO
FROM tableA
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 'NO is in tableBB' FROM tableBB 
            WHERE tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO AND tableBB.GRO_NO = 62)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 'NO is in tableBB' FROM tableBB 
            WHERE tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO AND tableBB.GRO_NO = 50)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 'NO is in tableBB' FROM tableBB 
            WHERE tableA.NO = tableBB.GRI_NO AND tableBB.GRO_NO = 70 
                 AND tableBB.IsActive = 1)
```

Comment: tblBB.GRO_NO IN (62,50,70)
--is the same than:

tblBB.GRO_NO = 62 OR tblBB.GRO_NO = 50 OR tblBB.GRO_NO = 70
--But don't give the same result than the original query

Comment: Depending on the query engine and statistics on the table you can get a different query plan when using IN (62,50,70) vs tblBB.GRO_NO = 62 OR tblBB.GRO_NO = 50 OR tblBB.GRO_NO = 70.  But the main benefit is concise behaviour. Can you expand on your comment that you don't get the same results as the previous query (please add to your question)?  I would hazard that my addition of DISTINCT is where the behaviour is different..

Comment: ignore that request, I see my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to write: 
`WHERE GRO_NO =62 OR GRO_NO =50 OR GRO_NO =70)`

in a **COMPACT syntax** is:
`WHERE GRO_NO IN (62,50,70)`

But as far as I know SQL, it seem there no alternative to write:
`WHERE GRO_NO =62 AND GRO_NO =50 AND GRO_NO =70)`
in a **COMPACT systax**

Answer (score 0):

Better option would be to use a single tableBB select, with an IN on the GRO_NO column

i.e.

...WHERE tableA.NO IN (select GRI_NO from tableBB where GRO_NO in (62,50,70))

,seeing as you have multiple selects for tableBB.

Comment: This will return different results than the Op's query.

Answer (score 0):

### You ask

Does an equivalent of sampleB2 exist for the AND keyword ?

### sampleB2:WHERE GRO_NO =62 AND GRO_NO =50 AND GRO_NO =70)

Would it be false always?
If so, you can write
WHERE GRO_NO <> GRO_NO